# How to display a message before each command in .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Before each command, display its effect(custom message) in the form of a message, and after its execution, make a condition for the system to wait for any key to be pressed in order to be able to view the results, and after each command clean the screen.
I've tried to write this

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Create testDir folder
MKDIR testDir
PAUSE
CLS
ECHO Remove testDir folder
RMDIR testDir
PAUSE
CLS
PAUSE
```

But is there a way to do this in a loop somehow?

Comment: Delete @Echo off, and preface any command you wish to suppress the Echoing of using the `@` Character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
call :exec "Create testDir folder" "MKDIR testDir"
call :exec "Remove testDir folder" "RMDIR testDir"
goto :eof

:exec
echo %~1
%~2
pause
cls
goto :eof
```

[untried]

Perhaps - simply provide the text and command as the two parameters to the internal subroutine `:exec`

You would need to be careful with escaping characters like `%!)><` though.